# Получить массив, в котором не было бы двух соседних чисел с одинаковым знаком

Tags: массивы, c++

не могу сообразить как написать алгоритм

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int n = 10;
    int m[n] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        //m[i] = (rand() % 100) * pow(-1, i);
        m[i] = (rand() % 100) * (i % 2 ? 1 : -1);
        cout << m[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Ответ на ваш вопрос это: * pow(-1, i) или * (i % 2 ? 1 : -1)